# How to add OAuth2+JWT authentication to a Spring Lemon based application

Tags: spring-lemon

I was pondering what would be the best way to incorporate OAuth2+JWT authentication to a [Spring Lemon](https://github.com/naturalprogrammer/spring-lemon) based application. Precisely, would it be possible by extending the [LemonSecurityConfig](https://github.com/naturalprogrammer/spring-lemon/blob/master/src/main/java/com/naturalprogrammer/spring/lemon/security/LemonSecurityConfig.java) class, or the source of Spring Lemon needs any change?